# Count number of rows returned in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

Are there any DB engines that allow you to run an `EXPLAIN` (or other function) where it will give you an approximate count of values that may be returned before an aggregation is run (not rows scanned but that actually would be returned)? For example, in the following query:

```
SELECT gender, COUNT(1) FROM sales JOIN (
       SELECT id, person FROM sales2 WHERE country='US'
       GROUP BY person_id
) USING (id)
WHERE sales.age > 20
GROUP BY gender
```

Let's say this query returns 3 rows after being aggregated, but would return 170M rows if unaggregated.

Are there any tools where you can run the query to get this '170M' number or does this have to do with complexity theory (or something similar) where it's almost just as expensive to run the query (without the final aggregation/having/sort/limit/etc) to get the count? In other words, doing a rewrite to:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sales JOIN (
       SELECT id, person FROM sales2 WHERE country='US'
       GROUP BY person_id
) USING (id)
WHERE sales.age > 20
```

But having to execute the query nonetheless.

As an example of using the current (mysql) explain to show how 'off' it is to get what I'm looking for:

```
explain select * from movies where title>'a';
# rows=147900
select count(1) from _tracktitle where title>'a';
# 144647 --> OK, pretty close


explain select * from movies where title>'u';
# rows=147900
select * from movies where title>'u';
# 11816 --> Not close at all
```

Comment: I think the problem here is the condition, to get only the rows who takes in consideration age > 20 you must "read" the data in some way so the work is also expensive. Without conditions you can count the rows numbers fetching the table properties. At least in a yes-SQL server. But any further comments about non-SQL will change completely your architechture.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli could you please clarify what you mean by yes-SQL and non-SQL? Do you mean having to read a data type that is something like xml/json or other?

Comment: yes, or making a non-sql database only for indexes and conditions.

Comment: Interesting question. So essentially you need "estimated or actual statistics" of one specific operator node in the tree, not just the root node of the plan. I've seen Oracle, DB2 and PostgreSQL doing that, though I haven't paid attention on how accurate the node count is.

Comment: Nevertheless, do to query rephrasing, you may find that there could be no "un-grouped" node in the plan, so there's nowhere to look in some cases. For example, in your specific query I can clearly see that smart optimizers (Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL again) may push the filtering predicate `sales.age > 20` to the inner subquery for early scanning optimization; if that's the case there won't be a representative operator node in the tree for the details you want.

Comment: This question is better suited for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: how close is _close enough_ as an approximation? You slightly answered your own question with those 2 examples. `EXPLAIN` does give you an approximation, but how close it is to the real result depends.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones for argument's sake let's say always within 10%.

Comment: If you ever want the answer to be Yes, you might want to propose it as a feature request to your favorite DBMS.  You're basically asking for programatic access to query optimizer estimates.  That stuff is in the EXPLAIN text (or whatever), and I think I vaguely recall it was accessible somehow or other in Microsoft SQL Server. But I don't think I've ever seen it exposed through an SQL function.

Comment: it feels like you're after something like [DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (table, index) WITH HISTOGRAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) where you will have row counts against buckets of values in given index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use MS SQL Server, you could tap into the same data the Optimiser is using for cardinality estimation: [`DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (table, index) WITH HISTOGRAM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Part of data sets you get back is per-column histogram, which is essentially number of rows for each value range found in the table.

You probably want to query the data programmatically, one way to achieve this would be to insert it into a temp table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #histogram (
    RANGE_HI_KEY datetime PRIMARY KEY,
    RANGE_ROWS INT,
    EQ_ROWS INT,
    DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS INT,
    AVG_RANGE_ROWS FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO #histogram 
EXEC ('DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (Users, CreationDate) WITH HISTOGRAM')

SELECT 'Estimate', SUM(RANGE_ROWS+EQ_ROWS) FROM #histogram WHERE RANGE_HI_KEY BETWEEN '2010-08-30 08:28:45.070' AND '2010-09-20 22:15:33.603'
UNION ALL
select 'Actual', COUNT(1) from Users u WHERE u.CreationDate BETWEEN '2010-08-30 08:28:45.070' AND '2010-09-20 22:15:33.603'
```

For example, check out what this same query run against [Stack Overflow Database](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1496772/histogram-test).

```
| -------- | ----- |
| Estimate | 98092 |
| Actual   | 11715 |
```

it seems like a lot but then keep in mind that the whole table has almost 15mil records.

### A note on precision and other gotchas

- The maximum number of histogram steps is capped at 200 - which is not a lot, so you are not getting guaranteed 10% margin of error, but neither does SQL Server.
- As you insert data into table, histograms may get stale so your results would get skewed even more.
- There are different ways to [update this data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), some are reasonably quick while others effectively require full table scan
- not all columns will have statistics. You can either [create it manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or (I believe) it gets created automatically if you run a search with the column as predicate

Answer (score 1):

MS Sql Server offers "execution plans". In the picture below I have queries and I press (Ctrl-L) to see the plans.

In my queries I return all records in first and just the count in the other, using the same table.

Look at metric corresponding to red arrows- estimated # of rows that WILL be scanned when queries are run. In this case, that number is same regardless whether count(*) or *, your point in case!

[image]